# Use Window XP ODBC connection on UNIX System

Tags: windows, unix, odbc, unixodbc

I would like to know is there any methods to test windows ODBC connection on UNIX.I have installed ODBC drive on UNIX.

Comment: What do you mean by "test windows ODBC connection on UNIX"? Do you mean you've created a Windows ODBC DSN and want to check it works from Unix? Do you mean you've installed an ODBC driver on UNIX for a database on Windows and want to check if it works? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

No. The only way I know is to create some kind of WebService/server that uses Windows ODBC and call remotely it from Linux.

Windows and Linux, and even Win32 and Win64 uses different binaries to connect to database and database drivers can use different settings on each platform.

Comment: Okays. Thank you for quick help !!